# Creating reusable action, reducer and effects for API calls in Ngrx Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to angular and ngrx and I am in the process of refactoring an ionic angular code base to use ngrx. The application has a lot of API calls with almost all requiring offline caching as well. Therefore I thought I could a create factory function that could build actions, reducers and effects based on api and db fetcher functions passed into it. The typings would be inferred from the fetcher functions.

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, concatLatestFrom, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import {
  createAction,
  createFeature,
  createReducer,
  on,
  props,
  Store,
} from '@ngrx/store';
import { exhaustMap, map, Observable, of, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Action } from 'rxjs/internal/scheduler/Action';
import { appFeature } from '../state/app/app.feature';

interface EntityParams<TData, TParams, TResult> {
  source: string;
  entityName: string;
  fetchCacheFirst?: boolean;
  apiFetcher: (params: TParams) => Observable<TData>;
  dbFetcher: (key: string) => Observable<TData | null>;
  dbPersistor: (payload: TData, key: string) => Observable<boolean>;
  resultTransform?: (param: TData) => TResult;
  // resultTransform?: (param: TData) => TResult;
}

export const createEntity = <TData, TParams, TResult = TData>({
  source,
  entityName,
  fetchCacheFirst = false,
  apiFetcher,
  dbFetcher,
  dbPersistor,
  resultTransform = (payload) => payload as any as TResult,
}: EntityParams<TData, TParams, TResult>) => {
  const actionType = `[${source}] (${entityName})`;
  /* ACTIONS */
  const initFetch = createAction(
    `${actionType} Init Fetching`,
    props<{ params: TParams }>()
  );
  const initFetchApi = createAction(
    `${actionType} Init fetch Data From API`,
    props<{ params: TParams }>()
  );
  const initFetchDb = createAction(
    `${actionType} Init fetch Data from DB`,
    props<{ params: TParams }>()
  );
  const fetchApiLoading = createAction(`${actionType} Loading - API`);
  const fetchApiSuccess = createAction(
    `${actionType} Successful Fetch - API`,
    props<{ payload: TData }>()
  );
  const initSaveApi = createAction(
    `${actionType} Init DB Save - API`,
    props<{ payload: TData; cacheKey: string }>()
  );
  const saveApiSuccess = createAction(`${actionType} Successful Save - DB`);
  const saveApiFail = createAction(`${actionType} Failed Save -DB`);
  const fetchApiFailed = createAction(
    `${actionType} Failed Fetch - API`,
    props<{ msg: string; error: any }>()
  );
  const fetchDbLoading = createAction(`${actionType} Loading - DB`);
  const fetchDbSuccess = createAction(
    `${actionType} Successful Fetch - DB`,
    props<{ payload: TData }>()
  );
  const fetchDbFailed = createAction(
    `${actionType} Failed Fetch - DB`,
    props<{ msg: string; error: any }>()
  );
  const fetchDbEmpty = createAction(`${actionType} Empty Fetch - DB`);

  /* Effects */

  const initFetchEffect = createEffect(
    (actions$ = inject(Actions), store$ = inject(Store)) => {
      return actions$.pipe(
        ofType(initFetch),
        // tap((res) => {
        //   console.log('came in ', res);
        // }),
        concatLatestFrom(() => [store$.select(appFeature.selectIsInternetOn)]),
        switchMap(([params, internetOn]) => {
          if (internetOn && fetchCacheFirst) {
            return [initFetchDb(params), initFetchApi(params)];
          }
          if (internetOn) {
            return [initFetchApi(params)];
          }
          return [initFetchDb(params)];
        })
      );
    },
    { functional: true }
  );

  const initSaveEffect = createEffect(
    (actions$ = inject(Actions)) => {
      return actions$.pipe(
        ofType(fetchApiSuccess),
        map(({ payload }) => {
          return initSaveApi({ cacheKey: actionType, payload: payload });
        })
      );
    },
    { functional: true }
  );

  const apiFetchEffect = createEffect(
    (actions$ = inject(Actions)) => {
      return actions$.pipe(
        ofType(initFetchApi),
        exhaustMap(({ params }) => {
          return apiFetcher(params);
        }),
        map((payload) => fetchApiSuccess({ payload }))
      );
    },
    { functional: true }
  );

  const saveApiEffect = createEffect(
    (actions$ = inject(Actions)) => {
      return actions$.pipe(
        ofType(fetchApiSuccess),
        exhaustMap(({ payload }) => dbPersistor(payload, actionType)),
        map(() => saveApiSuccess())
      );
    },
    { functional: true }
  );

  const dbFetchEffect = createEffect(
    (actions$ = inject(Actions)) => {
      return actions$.pipe(
        ofType(initFetchDb),
        exhaustMap(() => {
          return dbFetcher(actionType);
        }),
        map((payload) => {
          if (payload) {
            return fetchDbSuccess({ payload });
          }
          return fetchDbEmpty();
        })
      );
    },
    { functional: true }
  );

  //   const _resultTransform = (payload: TData) =>
  //     resolveCallback(resultTransform, payload);

  const transform = (data: TData) => resultTransform(data);

  interface InitialState {
    loading: boolean;
    error: any;
    data: ReturnType<typeof transform> | null;
    source: 'none' | 'API' | 'DB';
  }

  const initialState: InitialState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: null,
    source: 'none',
  };

  const feature = createFeature({
    name: entityName,
    reducer: createReducer(
      initialState,
      on(fetchApiSuccess, (state, { payload }) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          data: transform(payload),
          loading: false,
          source: 'DB',
        };
      }),
      on(fetchApiFailed, (state, { error }) => ({
        ...state,
        error,
        loading: false,
        source: 'API',
      })),
      on(fetchApiLoading, (state) => ({
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        source: 'API',
      })),
      on(fetchDbSuccess, (state, { payload }) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          data: transform(payload),
          loading: false,
          source: 'DB',
        };
      }),
      on(fetchDbFailed, (state, { error }) => ({
        ...state,
        error,
        loading: false,
        source: 'DB',
      })),
      on(fetchDbLoading, (state) => ({
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        source: 'DB',
      }))
    ),
  });

  return {
    name,
    initialState,
    transform,
    // resultTransform,
    feature,
    effects: {
      initFetchEffect,
      initSaveEffect,
      apiFetchEffect,
      dbFetchEffect,
      saveApiEffect,
    },
    actions: {
      fetchApiLoading,
      fetchApiSuccess,
      fetchApiFailed,
      fetchDbLoading,
      fetchDbSuccess,
      fetchDbFailed,
      initFetch,
      initFetchApi,
      initFetchDb,
      initSaveApi,
      saveApiFail,
      saveApiSuccess,
      fetchDbEmpty,
    },
  };
};
```

I also created an injectable class with all the necessary fetcher functions defined that made use of the apiService and dbService.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEntities {
  storage = inject(StorageService);
  authService = inject(AuthApiService);
  dbPersistor = <T>(payload: T, key: string) => {
    return this.storage.set(key, payload);
  };
  dbFetcher = <T>(key: string) => {
    return this.storage.get<T>(key);
  };

  loginFetcher = (params: { user: User; backendUrl: string }) => {
    return this.authService.login(params.user, params.backendUrl);
  };
  userDetailsFetcher = (params: { userId: string; companyId: string }) => {
    console.log('came in here ');
    return this.authService.getUserDetails(params.userId, params.companyId);
  };

  userDetailsEntity = createEntity({
    source: 'auth',
    entityName: 'userDetails',
    apiFetcher: this.userDetailsFetcher,
    dbFetcher: this.dbFetcher,
    dbPersistor: this.dbPersistor,
  });

  loginEntity = createEntity({
    source: 'auth',
    entityName: 'login',
    apiFetcher: this.loginFetcher,
    dbFetcher: this.dbFetcher,
    dbPersistor: this.dbPersistor,
  });

  loginFeature = this.userDetailsEntity.feature;
  userDetailsFeature = this.userDetailsEntity.feature;

  loginEffect = createEffect(
    (
      actions = inject(Actions),
      store = inject(Store),
      userDetailsEntity = this.userDetailsEntity,
      loginEntity = this.loginEntity
    ) => {
      return actions.pipe(
        ofType(triggerLogin),
        tap((payload) => {
          store.dispatch(
            userDetailsEntity.actions.initFetch({
              params: {
                userId: payload.user.loginid,
                companyId: payload.user.loginid,
              },
            })
          );
        }),
        switchMap(({ user }) => {
          return actions.pipe(
            ofType(userDetailsEntity.actions.fetchDbSuccess),
            map((res) => ({
              backendUrl: res.payload.backend_url,
              user,
            }))
          );
        }),
        map((res) =>
          loginEntity.actions.initFetch({
            params: {
              user: res.user,
              backendUrl: res.backendUrl,
            },
          })
        )
      );
    },
    { functional: true }
  );

}
```

But I am facing issues when trying to register the reducers created in this class since provideState function inside bootstrapApplication requires a pure function for the reducer. How can I register the reducer or better yet, how can I simplying the process of creating these reusable actions, reducers and effects.

I have tried to inject the apiService and dbService inside the fetcher functions while only using createEntity to create the effects and reducer which could then be exported. But this was causing injection errors.